# completely remove the title bar of tabs

Tags: java, netbeans

[img example http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/6873/guice.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/6873/guice.png)

Hi guys, I was wondering if there was any way to completely remove the title bar of the tabs (i.e 'tab2', 'tab3' e.t.c).

At the moment i am only able to use jTabbedPane1.setTitleAt(0, null); to remove the text in the title bar (or in netbeans just clear the text) but is there a way to completely hide the tab title bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could call them " ". If you want to hide them completely, why do you want a tab bar without a tab bar?  You could just have different panels you swap around.

Comment: Basically i will be calling each tab when a button is clicked (as though it were a panel). The main reason why i want a tab without a tab bar is because i have tabs within tabs as shown in the image above. thanks

Comment: also "" does what null does (removes the text)... my main problem is the bar itself

Comment: I would have panels with tabs in them.

Comment: @tofwiz : Then why not use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), for this kind of behaviour :-)